# "relative path potentially not safe" error with "find ... -delete" on macOS

Tags: find, osx

I'm trying to delete all files containing a certain text like this:

```
$ find ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/* -exec grep -l "text to search for" '{}' \; -delete
/Users/build/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/06060826-3fb2-4d71-82c6-7b9d309b08d6.mobileprovision
find: -delete: /Users/build/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/06060826-3fb2-4d71-82c6-7b9d309b08d6.mobileprovision: relative path potentially not safe
```

However, as you can see, it's throwing a warning and then does not delete the file. How can I resolve this error?

This is on a Mac.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

macOS `find` is based on an older version of FreeBSD `find` whose `-delete` would not remove the files that were given as argument.

When you do:

```
find dir/* ... -delete
```

Your *shell* is expanding that `dir/*` glob into a list of file paths (excluding the hidden ones, while `find` itself will not exclude the hidden files it finds in any of those dirs), so `find` receives something like:

```
find dir/dir1 dir/dir2 dir/file1 dir/file2... ... -delete
```

If `dir/file1` matches macOS `find`'s `-delete` will refuse to delete it. It will happily delete a `dir/dir1/.somefile` if it matches though.

That was [changed in FreeBSD in 2013](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base?view=revision&revision=253886), but the change apparently didn't make it to macOS. Here, the work around is easy: use `find dir` (or `find dir/` if you want to allow for `dir` to be a symlink to a directory  and `find` to descend into it) instead of `find dir/*`. So, in your case:

```
find ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/ \
  -exec grep -l "text to search for" '{}' \; -delete
```

Or use the [more efficient `grep -l --null | xargs -0` approach](/a/497670).

Comment: Now works on macOS (bigsur 11.5.2) if you add `-mindepth` to the call as per another answer. Both `dir/*` and `dir/` same results.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this problem on macOS deleting everything *except* archives from a directory tree:

```
find top ! -name "*.tar.gz" -print -delete
... snip ...
top
find: -delete: top: relative path potentially not safe
```

The solution was adding `-mindepth 1` to exclude the top directory

```
find top/path -mindepth 1 ! -name "*.tar.gz" -print -delete
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:
`find ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/ -type f -name "name to match" -delete`

Edit - first code is not abswer for question, try this:
`find ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/ -type f -exec grep -l --null "pattern in file" {} + | xargs -0 rm`

Comment: This is searching for a filename pattern. OP wants to find files which contain a certain string/text.

Comment: @MichaelD. Oh, you are right, my bad.

Comment: You can't use `xargs` in general on the output of `find`, but especially here, it won't work as the paths of the files contain spaces (all whitespace, quotes backslashes are a problem with `find | xargs`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas But option -d '\n' can handle it, right?

Comment: @Matej, `-d` is a GNU extension not supported by macOS `find` and still has problems with file names containing newline characters. If you have to use `rm`, use `-exec rm {} +` instead of `xargs`. If you have to use `xargs` use `find -print0 | xargs -0 rm` (also GNU extensions, but supported by macOS).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for the info, I edited answer.

Comment: No, I meant `-exec grep -q pattern {} \; -print0 | xargs -0 rm`. macOS `grep` should also support GNU's `--null` option so `-exec grep -l --null pattern {} + | xargs -0 rm` should also work (and avoid running one grep per file).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Now it's correct and faster, right?

Comment: Yes. It's correct (there are some race condition issues linked to using `xargs rm` instead of `-delete`, but probably not worth working around here as we're presumably not removing files from a directory  under control of potentially malicious actors).

Answer (score 0):

This is searching for string `err` in all files in `/var/log/` recursive.

I'm not sure if `cut`, `uniq` and `xargs` is available on Mac and this is not using `find`.

```
grep -r "err" /var/log/ | cut -d: -f1 | uniq | xargs echo
```

Replace `echo` with `rm` to delete the files.

Comment: 'find', `cut`, `uniq` and `xargs` are _standard_ Unix utilities available on _any_ Unix platform.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the star sign (`*`) in the folder path (right after `find`) to a dot (`.`)

i.e., `find dir/* ... -delete` ==> `find dir/. ... -delete`

Answer (score 0):

For me, this simply worked, using the -name option (`find <root_dir> -name <glob_pattern>`), instead of using globbing in the root path itself:

```
find ./tmp -name "*.json" -ctime +60s -type f -delete
```

thanks to this answer here on this same page for inspiration ;) https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/573178/411724

Comment: oops just realized this isn't exactly what OP is about, but since I had this error for doing the above (using glob for base path) I guess this might help others too.